# How to fix "ImportError: No module named error"

Tags: elastalert

I installed elastalert from `git clone https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert.git` and integrated with slack tool but when I try to run elastalert using command `python -m elastalert.elastalert --verbose --rule example_frequency.yaml` I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elastalert-0.2.1-py2.7.egg/elastalert/elastalert.py", line 29, in <module>
    from . import kibana
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elastalert-0.2.1-py2.7.egg/elastalert/kibana.py", line 4, in <module>
    import urllib.error
ImportError: No module named error
```

I expect output of getting alerts in slack tool

Answer (score 2):

I just have the same problem. I used python 2.7 to install elastalert.

So I remove elastalert and reinstall it with python36

```
pip uninstall elastalert
sudo yum install python36 gcc python36-devel -y 
sudo yum install python36-setuptools -y 
sudo easy_install-3.6 pip 

cd elastalert/
pip3.6 install "setuptools>=11.3"
python3.6 setup.py install
pip3.6 install -r requirements.txt
pip3.6 install elastalert

python36 -m elastalert.elastalert
```

Hope useful for you or someone that need